# How can I direct @mock.patch to correct path?

Tags: python, testing

So in my Desktop root directory, I have a test directory, which is where my test file sits:

```
'/Desktop/test_directory/test_my_code.py'
```

In my root Desktop directory, I also have another directory which is where my code sits:

```
'/Desktop/directory_containing_my_code/my_code.py'
```

Inside test_my_code.py I have a unit test, where I am using @mock.patch.
And I want to direct it to point to a class that sits in my_code.py.

But I'm not sure how to do it.

I tried:

```py
@mock.patch('/Users/patrickchong/Desktop/test_directory/test_my_code.someClass')
```

But when I run my unit test its clear the class was not mocked out.